# Finding minimum element from first list

Tags: java, optimization, java-8

I have one function which takes 2 List as a parameter. The end result which we want is to check
from the first list, How many elements are less than equals to each element from the second List?

For Example:

```
firstlist = [1,4,2,4]
secondList = [3,5]
```

Output = [2,4] 
Explaination: 
secondList[3] is >= firstList[1,2] So total is 2.
secondList[5] is >= firstList[1,4,2,4] so total is 4.

I have wrriten a solution but that is not optimize one.

```
   public  List<Integer> counts(List<Integer> teamA, List<Integer> teamB) {
       // Write your code here
       int[] b = teamB.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
       int[] a = teamA.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
       int counter;
       List<Integer> goals = new ArrayList<>();
       for (int i= 0;i<b.length;i++){
           counter= 0;
           for (int j =0;j < a.length; j++){
               if (a[j] <= b[i]){
                   counter++;
               }
           }
           goals.add(counter);
       }
       return goals;

   }
```

Comment: Does it give the correct result? If not what is the problem and if it does what do you want to improve? (Note that you could iterate on teamA and teamB directly instead of creating arrays just for the sake of it)

Comment: This looks like a learning exercise, so it's best to give it a try yourself. Take a stream from teamB and map each element to the count of elements less than it from teamA, and collect back to a list.

Comment: @assylias : Yes, The above is working, It will take longer time incase of too many element in the list, Since we are using for loop and go through each element

Comment: The solution you have accepted (using streams) also uses a loop behind the scene - the complexity is the same and the stream construct will at best perform the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use streams to simplify your code. If you're using lists, then stick to lists. Arrays are usually faster but harder to deal with.

```java
public static List<Integer> counts(List<Integer> teamA, List<Integer> teamB) {
    //Stream teamB and map each value to a result
    return teamB.stream().map(b -> 
        //Result is count of elements from teamA that are <= b
        (int) teamA.stream().filter(a -> a <= b).count()
    ).collect(Collectors.toList()); //Collect result stream into a list
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reduce the time complexity then you can sort the first list and for every element in the second list apply Binary search to find the numbers which are less.

This way the time complexity will be brought down from `O(N*M)` to `O(Mlog(N))`

Comment: +1 for an actual optimization suggestion. I believe it shall precisely be `O(N logN) + O(M logN)` hence worst case would be `max(O(N logN),  O(M logN))`